# Python Regex: why does this not work?

Tags: python, regex, replace, substitution

Why does this not work?

```
re.sub('\\b[a@](\\W|[a@])*[s5$](\\W|[s5$])*[s5$](\\W|[s5$])*($|\\W)', '*', '@ss')
```

I do not see why `@ss` is not replaced by `*`. Similarly, `@55` is not replaced.

These are replaced: a55, a5s, as5, ass

Thank you!

Comment: just clarifying that s looks like 5 and $ and 'a' looks like @

Comment: Wouldn't `re.sub(r'[a@][s5$]{2}', '*', '@ass')` be much simpler and give the same result, or am I missing something?

Comment: yes, that would work. but iam writing a general regex that would work for everything :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `@` is not a word character, and thus the first `\b` is not matched.

This is my suggestion:

```
re.sub('(\\ba|@)(\\W|[a@])*[s5$](\\W|[s5$])*[s5$](\\W|[s5$])*($|\\W)', '*', '@ss')
```

(Replacing `\b[a@]` with `(\ba|@)`)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a pair of parentheses around the first section. Try this:

```
re.sub('(\\b[a@])*(\\W|[a@])*[s5$](\\W|[s5$])*[s5$](\\W|[s5$])*($|\\W)', '*', '@ss')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying a sort of "profanity" check - I would take the logic out the regex.

```
look_alike = {'@': 'A', '$': 'S'}
test_string = ''.join(look_alike.get(c, c) for c in your_string.upper()) # also look at `string.translate`
```

Then `if 'ASS' in test_string` - or similar with word boundaries using an re.